# Terraform if statement inside of resource definition

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, terragrunt

I am deploying applications to my kubernetes cluster using the helm_release terraform module. I am attempting to get a single value stored in AWS SSM to be passed into the helm chart values file. This particular value is only required for one helm chart. I would like to not retrieve or pass in this value for all helm charts, so I am trying to set an if statement in the helm_release resource if the chart_name variable is equal to the chart I need to set the value for. For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
resource "helm_release" "example" {
  name  = var.chart_name
  repository = var.repository
  chart      = var.chart_name
  namespace = var.namespace
  create_namespace = var.create_namespace
  verify = false
  timeout = var.timeout
  repository_username = var.repo_username
  repository_password = var.repo_token
  
  # custom value from SSM would be set here. This is where I would like to perform the conditional check:
  # i.e. 
  # if var.chart_name = "some-chart":
  set_sensitive = [
    {
      path  = "firstEndpoints"
      value = data.aws_ssm_parameter.first_endpoints
    },
    {
      path  = "secondEndpoints"
      value = data.aws_ssm_parameter.second_endpoints
    },
  ]

  # dynamic values for all charts are passed in through terragrunt inputs (not super relevant here)
  dynamic "set" {
    for_each = var.dynamic_values
    
    content {
      name = set.value.name
      value = set.value.value
    }
  }
}
```

Long story short, is it possible to define conditionals within a terraform resource, rather than defining it on the entire resource?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify conditional logic within a resource parameter using a ternary with the expected syntax:

```
set_sensitive = var.chart_name == "some-chart" ? [
  {
    path  = "firstEndpoints"
    value = data.aws_ssm_parameter.first_endpoints
  },
  {
    path  = "secondEndpoints"
    value = data.aws_ssm_parameter.second_endpoints
  },
] : null
```

As expected this will assign the custom `list(object)` value for the specified chart name, and the parameter will be omitted completely otherwise.

Comment: This comes with the caveat that the data block being references will always be fetched, even if unused.